# change table cell background-color, when radiobutton is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a matrix of radiobuttons in a table

```
<table class="example_table">
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <colgroup></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radio1_1" name="radio_group_1" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio1_2" name="radio_group_1" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio1_3" name="radio_group_1" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio1_4" name="radio_group_1" type="radio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radio2_1" name="radio_group_2" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio2_2" name="radio_group_2" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio2_3" name="radio_group_2" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio2_4" name="radio_group_2" type="radio"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radio3_1" name="radio_group_3" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio3_2" name="radio_group_3" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio3_3" name="radio_group_3" type="radio"></td>
    <td><input id="radio3_4" name="radio_group_3" type="radio"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want two things-

- On mouseover I want the rows and columns over which the mouse is hovering in a different color.
- The cells with checked radiobuttons should have a different background-color.

I thought I'd use some jQuery and I figured out the first part but the second I can't seem to get right. My code for the first part is

```
$(function(){

  $(".example_table").delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function(e){

    if (e.type == 'mouseover'){
      $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
    } else{
      $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");

    }

  });

});
```

And of course my CSS:

```
.hover {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.checked {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.not_checked {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

Also is there a way to realise this second part without the `colgroup` tags? And of course any advice for the second part?

Comment: You must put table cells (`<td>` or `<th>`) inside your table rows(`<tr>`) in your html.

Comment: ups i forgot that, thanks!:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that will work without the colgroup's.

```
$(function(){
    $(".example_table").delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function(e){
        if (e.type == 'mouseover'){
            $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
            var i = $(this).parent().find('td').index(this) + 1;
            $(this).closest('table').find('td:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('hover');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('table').find('tr, td').removeClass('hover');
       }
    }); 
    $(".example_table").delegate('input', 'click', function(e){
        $(this).closest('table').find('td.checked input:not(:checked)')
            .closest('td').removeClass('checked');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('td').addClass('checked');
        }
    });

});
```

Basically, we find a column-index, and then find all td's that are at that same index, and give them the hover class as well.

The second part watches for click event on the radio buttons, and then does two things:

1. Finds all unchecked radio buttons that are in td's with the checked class, and removes the class
2. Checks the currently clicked radio button, and adds the checked class if necessary.

It's a bit more complicated than you might first expect, because radio buttons get unchecked without clicking on them - it's triggered by clicking on another radio button in the same group.

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mCPXH/

Comment: Updated to handle checked as well.